# Using diff of two strings to suggest a unique string (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a Python/Django website I maintain, users keep unique usernames at sign up. While registering, if a username isn't available, they have to guess another one.

Sometimes users have to contend with multiple "username already exists" messages before they're able to sign up.

I want to ameliorate this issue via suggesting a username *based upon the already used username they currently put in*. Can someone illustrate a neat Python solution for this?

---

I haven't tried anything yet. But I was thinking what would work is taking the current nickname the user wants, and then somehow doing an `ordinal` based `diff` with 4-5 *neighboring* nicknames from the DB (these I can easily query).

The diffs that are found can then somehow be used to *guess* an available nickname for the user, which is also sufficiently based on the one they already wanted. Something like that. Being a neophyte, I'm still trying to wrap my head around a viable solution.

Comment: Lazy solution: allow duplicate usernames, and require unique email addresses instead.

Comment: If you want to suggest 5 nicknames, you can create: 2 using name and surname variations and 3 using the already used nickname and a number variable, for example... How you'll combine or create the new usernames is up to you.

Comment: Folks, email address/surnames aren't a part of my sign up process. It's virtually two steps: username and password. Everything else is delayed to *after* registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have 5 suggestions and the user only provides a username he likes to use you could do the following.

Just start a counter from 1 to 100, append that number to the username and check if it is in the database. If not then save that suggestion in a list.

If that list has 5 entries, show them to your user to choose from.

Comment: I thought of that, but there's a criticism: this leads to more DB queries before I get to the right answer (although I can optimize the number of queries, but it's still inefficient). I do think that `ordinal` diffs can somehow be used to accurately predict precisely what unique username to suggest to the user, without needing to do extra DB queries (catch my drift?). And yes, I'd give the user 4-5 choices.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. lets say you have 2 usernames in your DB "cat" and "dog" which username would you suggest if the new user request "dog" as well?

Comment: Check this out to see what ASCII based ordinals are: http://www.linuxnix.com/pfotd-python-ord-function-examples/ That would give you an idea. And here's a converter you can use to get the ASCII codes: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/

Comment: I read this but still don't know how to determine usernames - nevertheless you need to check if they are already in the DB, don't you? So why don't you generate usernames with numbers at the end and do only one query which of them exists - and from the others you present 5 to the requestor?